# WKWebView in iOS not accepting session Cookie

Tags: ios, swift, hybrid-mobile-app, wkwebview, crosswalk

I am using WKWebView and not sure how to set the cookie policy to accept cookie.

I faced similar issue in UIWebView and below code fixed it.

```
let cookieStorage = NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage()
cookieStorage.cookieAcceptPolicy = NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicy.Always
```

How to i accept cookie in WKWebView?

```
Set-Cookie  JSESSIONID=V1nCXN2H7X8jvtpV512slqy1dGZrNLHrYnVfVhz4NGpghh0mPtl1!1773700448; path=/; HttpOnly
```

My session cookie looks like above and this is not getting set so i am not able to maintain my session.

Any help is much appreciated.

*Note:- I am using Crosswalk https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/cordova.html*

Comment: did you ever get a solution here?

Comment: No. I still could not get it to working.